# OpenCV imread could not open or find image

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, imread

I'm doing a project with OpenCV. I am trying to run a simple code:

```
#include<opencv2/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("test.jpg", 1);

    if (!img2.data)                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        cv::waitKey(5000);
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Working" << endl;
        cv::waitKey(5000);
    }

return 0;
}
```

My project is a lot more bigger then this, however something simple like this isn't working for me. I have tried many things such as full path names `//` and `\\`, even tried an IplImage and convert it into Mat still no luck.

I have tried many different file types as well. If it helps I have coded it to stop the application after hitting any button, that does not work as it isn't taking any input from my keyboard.

How can I determine what is wrong?

Comment: Almost always this kind of error is caused because your program isn't looking for the file where you think it is. Where have you put the file in relation to the program? How are you running the program? These details matter.

Comment: So even if you try to add full path of image, its not writing "Working" ?. It will not wait a keyboard action because you dont have a window. What is your operating system? Try to edit the question with the full path of image to be able to see how it looks like.

Comment: Amazingly it worked as soon as i set it to Release rather then Debug. is there a reason that worked? or shall i just be happy it worked

Comment: @VijayYadav there are indeed differences between both versions.As per the [documentation](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html): Debug has features that exist so you can find and resolve easier bugs inside your application. Release is an optimized version, where the goal is to make the application run as fast as possible. In short, in release mode you must use release libraries, in debug mode use debug libraries. Make sure you are not mixing the two.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue including the part about it only working in release mode. I found out I was using the release libraries for both release and debug. Because I had followed the [tutorial on the OpenCV website for visual studio](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html) (incorrectly albeit), I changed the .lib folder to the correct d.lib and that fixed it.